# Mapping array value to JSON in JOLT

Tags: json, jolt

This is my JSON example:

```
{
  "totalElements": 168,
  "columns": {
    "dimension": {
      "id": "variables/daterangehour",
      "type": "time"
    },
    "columnIds": [
      "1"
    ]
  },
  "rows": [
    {
      "itemId": "119050300",
      "value": "00:00 2019-06-03",
      "data": [
        120,
        10
      ]
    },
    {
      "itemId": "119050805",
      "value": "05:00 2019-06-08",
      "data": [
        98,
        12
      ]
    },
    {
      "itemId": "119050923",
      "value": "23:00 2019-06-09",
      "data": [
        172,
        8
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

This is my JOLT:

```
[{
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "rows": {
        "*": {
          "value": "[&1].date",
          "data": {
            "*": "[&2].metric1"
          }
        }
      }
    }
}
]
```

What it outputs is:

```
[ {
  "date" : "00:00 2019-06-03",
  "metric1" : [ 120, 10 ]
}, {
  "date" : "05:00 2019-06-08",
  "metric1" : [ 98, 12 ]
}, {
  "date" : "23:00 2019-06-09",
  "metric1" : [ 172, 8 ]
} ]
```

However what I am trying to output is this:

```
[ {
  "date" : "00:00 2019-06-03",
  "metric1" : 120
  "metric2" : 10
}, {
  "date" : "05:00 2019-06-08",
  "metric1" 98
  "metric2: 12
}, {
  "date" : "23:00 2019-06-09",
  "metric1" : 172
  "metric2" : 8
} ]
```

How do I map to specific array values rather than it returning the whole lot? It seems like it is around the wildcard on the metric1 line to select the first item but I cant find any code which does this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use the wildcard as below, it means that every item of `data` array should be mapped to the key `[&2].metric1`, which makes `metric1` field an array.

```
"data": {
    "*": "[&2].metric1"
}
```

What you should do is map the 1st element (element at index `0`) of `data` array to `metric1` key and 2nd element (element at index `1`) to `metric2` key as follows.

```
[
{
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
        "rows": {
            "*": {
                "value": "[&1].date",
                "data": {
                    "0": "[&2].metric1",
                    "1": "[&2].metric2"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
]
```

Comment: Thank you very much